# Bind First ListView slected items to second ListView

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml, listview

I have first and second ListView, as shown in the image:

[image]

I populated the first ListView, using this code

```
class CategoriesList
{
    public string Category_Names { get; set; }
    public double Category_Amount { get; set; }


    public static List<CategoriesList> get_CategoryList()
    {
        try
        {
            SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("  Data Source=system.sqlite; Version=3; Compress=True; ");
            con.Open();
            string query = " SELECT category_id, category_name, amount FROM acc_income_category WHERE deleted = 0 ORDER BY category_name ASC ";
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, con);

            SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            var categories = new List<CategoriesList>();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                CategoriesList cl = new CategoriesList();

                cl.Category_Names = dr.GetString(1);
                cl.Category_Amount = dr.GetDouble(2);

                categories.Add(cl);
            }

            con.Close();

            return categories;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

This is my Xaml Code

```
<ListView x:Name="ListBox_Category_Names" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        Width="auto"  Height="300" SelectionMode="Single"  Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,10,0" 
                                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectionChanged="ListBox_Category_Names_SelectionChanged" 
                                                >
                                        <ListView.View>
                                            <GridView>

                                                <GridViewColumn Header="Category Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Category_Names}" Width="280"  />
                                                <GridViewColumn Header="Amount " DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Category_Amount, ConverterCulture=ig-NG, StringFormat=\{0:C\}}"  Width="130"  />

                                            </GridView>
                                        </ListView.View>
                                    </ListView>


                                    <ListView x:Name="ListBox_Selected_Category" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Width="auto"  Height="300" SelectionMode="Single"  Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ListBox_Category_Names}"    >
                                        <ListView.View>
                                            <GridView>

                                                <GridViewColumn Header="Category Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Category_Names}" Width="250"  />

                                                <GridViewColumn Header="Amount" >
                                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <TextBox x:Name="txtBox_amount" Text="{Binding Category_Amount, ConverterCulture=ig-NG, StringFormat=\{0:C\}}"  Width="200" Height="35"  />
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                </GridViewColumn>

                                            </GridView>
                                        </ListView.View>
                                    </ListView>
```

This is the Code thats Loads the First ListBox

```
ListBox_Category_Names.ItemsSource = CategoriesList.get_CategoryList();
```

Not MVVM

Now I'm stuck cause I need to bind the First ListView Selected Items to the Second ListView. Please, I really need help, been stuck with this for the past three (3) weeks. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your `xaml` code as well?

Comment: How you are assigning items source of your first list view? Are you using MVVM?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways: 1) code behind 2) mvvm

**First way**:handle the button click in the code behind:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArguments arg)
{
  List<ListViewItem> mySelectedItems = new List<ListViewItem>();

  foreach(ListViewItem item in myListView.SelectedItems)
  {
    mySelectedItems.Add(item);
  }
}
```

**Second way** bind the multiple selection in the pattern of mvvm, for that look at:

[Part 1](http://grokys.blogspot.co.il/2010/07/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-i.html)

[Part 2](http://grokys.blogspot.co.il/2010/07/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-ii.html)

[Part 3](http://grokys.blogspot.co.il/2010/07/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-iii.html)

Comment: Thanks @Isreal Altar, But i have tried the first solution, but its giving me this exception  " Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'School.CategoriesList' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem'."